# Selectively copy and paste rows with given criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select rows in a table based on the word "Yes" being present in column J.

I have a table going from column A to J, and I want to select the rows where there is a "Yes" in column J and paste only those rows into a new sheet.

Once selected, I need to copy these rows to a new sheet or word document.

I have tried a range of forumulas, this is for Windows MS Excel software, using a VBA Macro.

I am using the following VBA, but having issues:

```
Sub Macro1()
 Dim rngJ As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngJ = Range("J1", Range("J65536").End(xlUp))
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    For Each cell In rngJ
        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy

            wsNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: *having issues* - what issues? Post the error message if that's what you're getting, or the expected and actual results if your code runs to completion.

Comment: `wsNew` is a worksheet.  You're likely getting an error when you do `wsNew.Sheets("Sheet1")...`?  I *think* you would want to just do `wsNew.Range("J66536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Paste`?

Comment: @BruceWayne -  agreed, though I think pasting an entire row starting at J might also cause an error?

Comment: Note: Don't hard code the last cell. Recent Excel verions have much more than 65536 rows use `Range("J" & Rows.Count)` instead. • And you might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Hi @jsheeran, thanks for getting back to me so quickly! My error message is 'Run Time Error 438, Object does not support this property or method'.

This occurs in the wsNew.Sheets line

Comment: @SJR - Good catch - OP may want `wsNew.Range("J66536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Paste` (I think that's a legit command...can't remember exactly where `EntireRow` would go)

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you for your suggestion! That stops an error coming up, but just creates a new blank sheet without pasting anything in..

Comment: You should qualify which sheet `RngJ`'s data is on. Currently it'll use whatever the active sheet is.  You want to do something like `set rngJ = Worksheets("SheetName").Range(...)`.  Also I suggest stepping through your code with `F8`, as it'll go line by line and you can more easily follow it and see where it goes awry.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thank you :) How do I not hard code the last cell? Can I just do Range("J1", Range("J").End.....?

Comment: You *could* do that, but it would make a rather ugly range.  I tend to do `Dim lastRow as Long // lastRow = Range("J" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` and use that, e.g. `Range("J" & lastRow + 1).Value = "New Text"`

Comment: @PKen, where exactly do you want to paste it?

Comment: @AAA to either a new generated sheet or an already existing sheet e.g. "FinalSpec"

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you :) Still struggling with this one: 
wsNew.Range("J66536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Paste 

I'm getting an error saying 'Object does not support this method'.

Comment: Why are you pasting in "J66536". You just want to paste in the new sheet, right?

Comment: @AAA yes I just want to paste into the new sheet, should I do wsNew.Range("J").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Paste

Comment: Thanks all so much for your help. I am still struggling to get the rows to paste into the new sheet where the column J in the original sheet has a "Yes" in the cell.

Comment: Do you need to use "J"?

Comment: So I could just have     wsNew.Range.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste ?? 
@AAA

Comment: @PKen, check my answer below, which works and is also more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than finding, copying and pasting for each cell, why not find all, then copy and paste once like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rngJ As Range
Dim MySel As Range

Set rngJ = Range("J1", Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

For Each cell In rngJ
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy Destination:= wsNew.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

It's better to avoid using `Select` as much as possible; see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10718179).

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyYesRowsToNewWorksheet()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'better define sheet by name ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheet")

    Dim DataRangeJ As Variant 'read "yes" data into array for faster access
    DataRangeJ = wsSource.Range("J1", wsSource.Range("J" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    Dim NextFreeRow As Long
    NextFreeRow = 1 'start pasting in this row in the new sheet

    If IsArray(DataRangeJ) Then        
        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = LBound(DataRangeJ) To UBound(DataRangeJ) 'loop through data array
            If DataRangeJ(iRow, 1) = "yes" Then
                wsNew.Rows(NextFreeRow).Value = wsSource.Rows(iRow).Value 'copy the values of the row
                NextFreeRow = NextFreeRow + 1
            End If
        Next iRow
    ElseIf DataRangeJ = "yes" Then 'if only the first row has data
        wsNew.Rows(NextFreeRow).Value = wsSource.Rows(1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The line

```
wsNew.Rows(NextFreeRow).Value = wsSource.Rows(iRow).Value
```

only copys the value without formatting. If you also want to copy the formatting replace it with

```
wsSource.Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=wsNew.Rows(NextFreeRow)
```

Comment: Hi @PEH, thank you so much for your help and kind explanation!
I get a mismatch error with this on the line@ For iRow = LBound(DataRangeJ) To UBound(DataRangeJ) 'loop through data array 

Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: no or only one "yes" in column J. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ 
Thanks for your help. This code manages to create a new sheet, but nothing gets copied over. I have a table going from column A to J, and I want to select the rows where there is a "Yes" in column J and paste only those rows into a new sheet...